# How to add a c# file to Visual Studio Solution Explorer at runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Consider the code snippet below for a split second:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      //...
      File.Create(path);
  }
```

This, obviously, creates a file in a given path. However, created file does not appear in the solution explorer.

How to extend this function, so that after running it, the newly created file would appear at the solution explorer and would be part of a project?

**Updated**

To add the newly created file to a project, just open and modify the .csproj file.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't really exist in runtime.....sure it does while you're developing the app, but once you deploy it somewhere, VS isn't part of the picture. Why do you think you need to add new files to the solution during runtime? What exactly is the purpose of this?

Comment: If you want to automatically generate code, that's possible, but then you would normally generate the files in a different project than the one you're including it to.

Comment: @PMF since you mention that it is possible. Do you have some directions, by any chance?

Comment: Before you get into the *how* of doing it, you should answer *why* you think you need to do this. There may be a better way of doing this that completely avoids this strange architecture.

Comment: @VytautasK As noted in the other comments, please describe your scenario. There are legitimate uses of code generators and many people use them, but how to generate your code (if at all it is necessary for your project) will depend on your overall use case.

Comment: It was just a small specific assignment I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the created file to the project, just open the `.csproj file` and add the [relevant code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015).

In each example, the following item declaration was used to include the file C:\MyProject\Source\Program.cs in the project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyItem Include="Source\Program.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```